# Как подключить задать значения из api в переменные для бота в телеграмме?

Tags: веб-программирование, api, telegram

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Создаю бота в телеграмме через сервис botmother и api я уже подключил, чтобы задавать в переменные актуальные значения курсов валют, использую для этого currencyAPI.Снизу приложил фотку API компонента. Задаюсь вопросом как задать в значения переменных значения валют из api? Буду рад если поможете или направите на правильный путь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответы от сервера хранятся в объекте `last_request`. Получить к ним доступ в компоненте можно с помощью двойных фигурных скобок. Например, так: `{{last_request.usdbtc}}`

Статья на эту тему в базе знаний Botmother: https://docs.botmother.ru/category/9904

Comment: Спасибо большое!